# How to detect screen TILT in android?

Tags: android, rotation

i am creating an app in which i want to detect screen tilt (when we turn our phone torwards right a little bit) and want to rotate imageview in this case (to 90 degrre). currently i am using this code but it just rotates the imageview in oncreate(when app starts running). i want to detect the screen tilt and want to rotate imageview in that case. how it can be achieved? Any help will be appreciated

```
Sensor accelator;
SensorManager sm;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_demo_img);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.demoimg);
    relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_main);
    //scaleGestureDetector=new ScaleGestureDetector(this,new ScaleListener());
    setlisteners();
    sm=(SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelator=sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sm.registerListener(this,accelator,SensorManager.AXIS_MINUS_X);
}
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "On Sensor Changed Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    imageView.setRotation(90);
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [OrientationEventListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html).

```
private OrientationEventListener createOrientationListener() {
    return new OrientationEventListener(this) {
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            System.out.println("orientation................."+orientation);
        }
    };
}
```

To start this listener inside `onCreate` method.

```
OrientationEventListener orientationListener = createOrientationListener();
orientationListener.enable();
```

If you turn your phone towards right direction it will trigger value from 1 to 90. Turn in all direction will give value upto 360. so you can use this value as per your requirement.

After use you can disable it.

```
orientationListener.disable();
```